# Smarty loop inside javascript

Tags: php, jquery, smarty

I am new on `smarty` i want a loop for data show on chart my code chart is as follows for example there is data is only for one record and i want it for a `array`. The location of array mentioned below and array is in `smarty` type `array` so how i would integrate it with `jquery` for my chart.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function () {
        var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer",
        {
        title:{
                text: "Simple Chart",
                fontSize: 30
            },
            animationEnabled: true,
            axisX:{ gridColor: "Silver",
                tickColor: "silver",
                valueFormatString: "DD/MMM"

            },toolTip:{shared:true},
            theme: "theme2",
            axisY: {
                gridColor: "Silver",
                tickColor: "silver"
            },legend:{
                verticalAlign: "center",
                horizontalAlign: "right"
            },data: [ /* want iteration for loop as smarty array */
            {type: "line",
                showInLegend: true,
                lineThickness: 2,
                name: "Visits",
                markerType: "square",
                color: "#F08080",
                dataPoints: [
                { x: new Date(2010,0,3), y: 650 },
                { x: new Date(2010,0,5), y: 700 },
                { x: new Date(2010,0,7), y: 710 },
                { x: new Date(2010,0,9), y: 658 },
                { x: new Date(2010,0,11), y: 734 },
                { x: new Date(2010,0,13), y: 963 },
                { x: new Date(2010,0,15), y: 847 },
                { x: new Date(2010,0,17), y: 853 },
                { x: new Date(2010,0,19), y: 869 },
                { x: new Date(2010,0,21), y: 943 },
                { x: new Date(2010,0,23), y: 970 }
                ]
            } /* loop will end here */
            ],
          legend:{
            cursor:"pointer",
            itemclick:function(e){
              if (typeof(e.dataSeries.visible) === "undefined" || e.dataSeries.visible) {
                e.dataSeries.visible = false;
              }
              else{
                e.dataSeries.visible = true;
              }
              chart.render();
            }
          }
        });
      chart.render();
    }
</script>
```

I want a array loop for data in this code as mentioned above

Comment: I think you should refer to this http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.function.foreach.tpl

Comment: What data you have in that array?

Comment: I prefer that you should create array in php as follows:
$data = [['x'  => 'new Date(2010, 0,3)', 'y' => 140], ['x'  => 'new Date(2010, 0,3)', 'y' => 140]]
and in javascript use simply json_encode($data); This is most appropriate way to write json data

Comment: thanks @PankajMakwana